# Accessing advanced metadata formats from ArcGIS REST API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, metadata, arccatalog

Esri allows us to choose the style of the metadata we would like to use:
[image]

Those styles allow you to add more specific metadata e.g. more description about a specific field like this:

**the problem is, that this extra metadata is not accessible from the REST API**, as you can see in the picture below:
[image]

the "extra" fields are nowhere to be found

Comment: "*though it may be easier just to copy and paste some elements or a hyperlink to a published metadata file into service/layer summaries when publishing*" Easier? If this was available, then you could automatically get the metadata without having to worry whether your export was up to date, not to mention exporting and linking to it for every layer you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While as you have discovered the ArcGIS Server REST API doesn't expose Metadata, ArcGIS Portal and ArcGIS Online now [support storing metadata](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/metadata.htm) for content items.  This supports the listed metadata styles only and doesn't extend to custom stylesheets.

If you did need to expose this metadata through the REST API then it should be possible by writing a [Server Object Extension](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/publish-services/linux/about-extending-services.htm), though it may be easier just to copy and paste some elements or a hyperlink to a published metadata file into service/layer summaries when publishing.

Comment: Got conformation from ESRI support for that as well.